# How to create PPS file in Visual Studio 2010 using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint

I have worked on ASP.NET with C# but no experience in visual studio to make Microsoft Office Applications.

Can you please suggest how can I do the below task :
I want to make a PPS file (Microsoft Power Point) in Visual Studio 2010 using ASP.NET with C#.

Also I want to add images/pictures in pps file and will send the file in email.

Comment: Do you need to do this from ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, I need to incorporate this pps functionality in ASP.NET code

Comment: You cannot use Office Interop from a server application. Just don't do it.

Comment: So Is there any other solution to perform the same task without using interop?

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents, if you're going to deploy your ASP.NET application to an environment that you can't control, stay away from Office automation. You can use [Office Open XML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) which doesn't require Office installed on the server. I think it is a bit more difficult than using automation, but it's worth because it's free and there are plenty of resources on the internet. One is the [Open XML developer](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) website.

The same thing applies to email sending, use the `System.Web.Mail` namespace rather than Outlook automation.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email is diff part.Use `smtp` or any other protocol to send email.To start pps with C# you find a sample here.[Power Point Automation Using C#](http://dotnet23.blogspot.com/2010/07/1.html) .
And You get Sending email sample here.[Sending Mail](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dchoksi/SendingMail02132007002923AM/SendingMail.aspx)

Comment: -1: Horrible advice: don't **ever** use Office Interop from a service-based application.

Answer (score 0):

here is couple of good turorials on how to automate the creation of ppt from c#

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718/

from the article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc163471%28en-us%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb960904%28v=office.12%29.aspx

and here is a short tutoral

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10068596/create-ppt-slides-through-cnet.aspx

here is how to send email with attachment

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-email-attachment.htm

i hope it will guide you to the right task

Comment: -1: ancient articles, and you're giving horrible advice about using Interop.